# How to deselect pre-selected group options in vue multi select?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-multiselect

I am using [vue multi select](https://vue-multiselect.js.org) plugin. I am using group select option to select the values group wise. I am storing the selected values in localstorage to maintain the preselected option by the user.
When I select the values for the group its working properly but when I preselect the values on page reload then the values are getting set properly but the select all option is not deselecting the selected values.

Is there a way to track group deselect option in vue multi select or is there a way in which I can use this vue multiselect plugin effectively and maintain the selected and deselected values.

Vue multiselect tag code is shown below with used props.

```
    <multiselect
  v-model="location"
  :options="options"
  :multiple="true"
  :close-on-select="false"
  :clear-on-select="false"
  :preserve-search="true"
  placeholder="Locations"
  label="name"
  track-by="name"
  :allow-empty="true"
  @input="updateOptions($event)"
  group-values="locationData"
  group-label="location"
  :group-select="true"
  :preselect-first="false"
>
  <template slot="selection" slot-scope="{ values, search, isOpen }">
    <span
      class="multiselect__single"
      v-if="values.length &amp;&amp; !isOpen"
    >{{ values.length }} Locations Selected</span>
  </template>
</multiselect>
```

Scripts :

```
  data() {
return {
  locations: {},
  location: {},
  options: [
    {
      location: "Select All",
      locationData: []
    }
  ]
};
```

}

I am setting the location array on load of the page.

Comment: Could you maybe replicate your code on this jsfiddle page(https://jsfiddle.net/py8du51m/2/). It would be the best place for me to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 computed: {
    options_length: function () {
        return this.item.options.length;
    }
},
methods:{

    onSelectChange (value) {
        if (value.length == this.options_length && this.selectedAll === null) {
        console.log(this.options_length);
            this.selectedAll = true;
        } else if (value.length == this.options_length && this.selectedAll === true) {
            this.selectedOptions = [];
            this.selectedAll = null;
        }
        // do the thing
    },
```